# how to open the route in the browser's new tab In laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

In laravel, how to open the route in the browser's new tab?
like this.
￼[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19qfH.png)

Comment: add target attribute  in anchor tag target="_blank"

Answer (score 0):

Just add `target="_blank"` in your anchor tag like:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp